# Is there any way to speed up ModuleFinder?

Tags: python

Is there any way to make this function for finding dependencies of a Python module smarter?  I'm running this on all 1900+ of my project files, and some of them take more than 1 second to process.

It looks like ModuleFinder calculates the dependencies of the module recursively, but I haven't found any way to make it re-use that information for the next file...

ps: I'm using the 2.7 port of pathlib

```
import sys, os
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
from pathlib import Path

def dependencies(fname, root=None):
    """Find all dependencies (i.e. imported modules) from fname without
       running it.

       If `root` is specified, only modules having __file__ attributes
       under this root is included.

       This function is quite slow..
    """
    assert fname.endswith('.py')

    res = set()
    finder = ModuleFinder()
    try:
        finder.run_script(fname)
    except:
        return []

    root = normpath(root, slash='/')
    prefix = len(root) + 1  # for trailing slash

    for name, mod in finder.modules.iteritems():
        if name.startswith('_'):
            continue
        modpath = normpath(mod.__file__, slash='/')
        if modpath.startswith(root):
            res.add(modpath[prefix:])

    return list(sorted(res))


def normpath(p, slash=None):
    """Return a canonical version of path ``p``.
    """
    res = ""
    if isinstance(p, Path):
        p = str(p.absolute())
    if p is not None:
        res = os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(p)))
    if slash is None:
        return res
    else:
        return res.replace('\\', slash)
```

Comment: Try instantiating `finder` outside of the `dependencies` function.

Comment: @unutbu then you get not only the dependencies of the module, but of all previous modules... :-(